# Do I need an article if the proper name already contains an article?

Tags: articles, proper-nouns

Please look at this phrase:

> the book by H.G. Wells “The Time Machine”

Is it OK to use the definite article with "book" if the book title already contains an article? Are the any rules for such cases?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The article is required in every example I can think of. Can you provide an example sentence where you think it could be omitted?

Comment: There is an incomplete example sentence posted. Suppose you say "I read book by H.G. Hells *The Time Machine*." It lacks a definite or indefinite article before 'book'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use an article with "book".

It doesn't matter that the title contains an article - you aren't referring to the title, you are referring to *the* book.

A good question to ask would be *what if the title contained a different article?*

Of course, if you were referring to Shakespeare's *A Midsummer Night's Dream*, it would be:

> *The* Shakespeare play "A Midsummer Night's Dream".

It is *the* book and *the* play because these are unique. If you were referring to an individual *copy* of the book, or a particular *production* of the play, you would use the indefinite article:

> A production of "A Midsummer Night's Dream".
> A copy of "The Time Machine".

Answer (score 0):

While the presence of an article in a proper noun may affect whether you put an(other) article immediately before the proper noun itself, it doesn’t have any further-reaching effects.